# Android - Blank RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-volley, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I was able to toast the JSON response from the URL and then when I went for displaying the same on a RecyclerView I get a blank output, but the tabs and the navigation drawer are present. There were no errors too while running the app. Am also using the Volley library.

Problem: I don't get any output on the RecylerView listing the services. I'll post the codes related to the RecyclerView here. Also I've posted the stack trace at the bottom.

**ServiceViewAdapter.java** **(The ADAPTER)**

```
public class ServiceViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServiceViewAdapter.ViewHolderService> {

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private ArrayList<Service> listServices = new ArrayList<>();
private VolleySingleton mVolleySingleton;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

public ServiceViewAdapter(Context context) {
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    mImageLoader = mVolleySingleton.getImageLoader();
}

public void setServiceList(ArrayList<Service> listServices){
    this.listServices = listServices;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, listServices.size());
}


static class ViewHolderService extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView imageViewService;
    private TextView textViewName;
    private TextView textViewOrgName;
    private TextView textViewPrice;
    private RatingBar ratingBarScoreRating;

    public ViewHolderService(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageViewService = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_list);
        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewOrgName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOrgName);
        textViewPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
        ratingBarScoreRating = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarScoreRating);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolderService onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_services_all, parent, false);
    ViewHolderService viewHolderService = new ViewHolderService(view);
    return viewHolderService;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderService holder, int position) {
    Service currentService = listServices.get(position);

    holder.textViewName.setText(currentService.getName());
    holder.textViewOrgName.setText(currentService.getOrgName());
    holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(currentService.getPrice()));
    holder.ratingBarScoreRating.setNumStars(4);

    String imageUrl = currentService.getImageUrl();
    if(imageUrl!=null){
        mImageLoader.get(imageUrl, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                holder.imageViewService.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listServices.size();
}

}
```

**FragmentAll.java (Fragment showing RecyclerView)**

```
public class FragmentAll extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private VolleySingleton mVolleySingleton;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ArrayList<Service> listServices = new ArrayList<>();
private ServiceViewAdapter mServiceViewAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerViewServices;

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FragmentAll newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentAll fragment = new FragmentAll();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public static String getRequestUrl() {
    return URL_SEARCH_BASE
            + URL_CHAR_QUESTION
            + URL_PARM_SEARCH
            + URL_CHAR_AMPERSAND
            + URL_PARM_PAGENO + MyApplication.HOME_PAGE_NUMBER;
}

public FragmentAll() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

    mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();

    sendJsonRequest();
}

public void sendJsonRequest() {

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest
            (
                    getRequestUrl(),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            listServices = parseJSONResponse(response);
                            mServiceViewAdapter.setServiceList(listServices);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }
            );
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}

private ArrayList<Service> parseJSONResponse(JSONArray response) {

    ArrayList<Service> listServices = new ArrayList<>();
    if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject serviceObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                long id = serviceObject.getLong(KEY_ID);
                String name = serviceObject.getString(KEY_NAME);
                long price = serviceObject.getLong(KEY_PRICE);

                String smallPictureUrl = null;
                if (serviceObject.has(KEY_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL)) {
                    smallPictureUrl = serviceObject.getString(KEY_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL);
                }

                JSONObject postedUserObject = serviceObject.getJSONObject(KEY_POSTED_USER);
                JSONObject profileObject = postedUserObject.getJSONObject(KEY_PROFILE);

                String orgName = profileObject.getString(KEY_ORG_NAME);
                int rating = profileObject.getInt(KEY_RATING);

                Service service = new Service();
                service.setId(id);
                service.setName(name);
                service.setPrice(price);
                service.setOrgName(orgName);
                service.setRating(rating);
                service.setImageUrl(smallPictureUrl);

                listServices.add(service);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
    return listServices;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);
    recyclerViewServices = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listAllServices);
    recyclerViewServices.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mServiceViewAdapter = new ServiceViewAdapter(getActivity());
    recyclerViewServices.setAdapter(mServiceViewAdapter);
    sendJsonRequest();
    return view;
}
}
```

**fragment_all.xml (The main fragment layout)**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listAllServices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**custom_services_all.xml (Single item in the fragment)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewOrgName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBarScoreRating"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewOrgName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
 />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewName"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**StackTrace (Log output)**

> 05-28 12:28:06.057    1644-1644/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 I/art﹕
> Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 05-28 12:28:06.183
> 1644-1654/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
> 05-28 12:28:06.270    1644-1644/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 I/ViewUtils﹕
> app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme
> instead. 05-28 12:28:06.463    1644-1664/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4
> D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true 05-28
> 12:28:06.476    1644-1644/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 D/﹕
> HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabb86940, tid
> 1644 05-28 12:28:06.514    1644-1644/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 D/Atlas﹕
> Validating map... 05-28 12:28:06.682
> 1644-1664/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 D/libEGL﹕ loaded
> /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so 05-28 12:28:06.683
> 1644-1664/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 D/libEGL﹕ loaded
> /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so 05-28 12:28:06.724
> 1644-1664/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 D/libEGL﹕ loaded
> /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so 05-28 12:28:06.767
> 1644-1664/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host
> Connection established 0xa3305120, tid 1664 05-28 12:28:06.815
> 1644-1664/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL,
> version 1.4 05-28 12:28:06.996    1644-1664/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4
> D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0 05-28 12:28:07.091
> 1644-1664/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib
> not implemented 05-28 12:28:07.091
> 1644-1664/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set
> EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3307440, error=EGL_SUCCESS 05-28
> 12:28:07.219    1644-1644/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 W/View﹕
> requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ImageView{31787f8
> V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0b006b app:id/selector} during layout:
> running second layout pass 05-28 12:28:07.219
> 1644-1644/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly
> called by android.widget.ImageView{1e42a4d1 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0
>
> ## 7f0b006b app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass 05-28 12:28:07.219    1644-1644/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 W/View﹕
>
> requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ImageView{3b3e0b36
> V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b006b app:id/selector} during layout:
> running second layout pass 05-28 12:28:07.243
> 1644-1644/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!
> The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 05-28
> 12:28:07.997    1644-1644/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4 I/Choreographer﹕
> Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
> main thread. 05-28 12:28:11.577    1644-1668/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4
> D/Volley﹕ [165] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for
> request=<[ ] http://myservicekart.com/public/search?search=&pageno=1
> 0x7b216334 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=4932], [size=262811], [rc=200],
> [retryCount=0] 05-28 12:28:11.597    1644-1644/com.piserve.geejo.mskv4
> D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 4962 ms: [ ]
> http://myservicekart.com/public/search?search=&pageno=1 0x7b216334
> NORMAL 1

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The output from the RecyclerView when running is blank.

Comment: can you help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your smallPictureUrl is still containing null. That's why your RecyclerView is not showing because listServices is empty till now.

You are parsing poster right??.from rotten tomatoes api??. Poster is also a Json object which contain three poster url.In between these you have to pars thumbnail Right??

So here you have to write

```
`JSONObject objPoster =   serviceObject.getJSONObject("posters");
 String smallPictureUrl = null;
            if (serviceObject.has(KEY_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL)) {
                smallPictureUrl = serviceObject.getString(KEY_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL);
            }
```

I hope its helps..